# TypeError: _this2.input.current.focus is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that I name it Invoice. In Invoice, I use UnderInvoice and SearchProduct component. UnderInvoice component involves some buttons (product, customer, …). SearchProduct component involves two textboxes (barcode, name) to search for products and a grid to show results. When I click on the product button, a modal opens to show SearchProduct. I want when the modal opened, focus on the barcode textbox, I create the ref in the constructor and assign it for txtBarcode variable. Then in the render() method of SearchProduct component, I render my input and set ref-attribute to equal the txtBarcode variable.And finally I call focus() on the txtBarcode’s current property in the componentDidMount() method. But when I click on product button I get this error : “TypeError: _this2.txtBarcode.current.focus is not a function”. What is my fault?
My code is something like this :
In SearchProduct component :

```
    export default class SearchProduct extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
this.txtBarcode = React.createRef();
}
componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // console.log("ref", this.txtBarcode);
      this.txtBarcode.current.focus();
    }, 1000);
  }
render() {
return (
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-6">
    <input
              id="productBarcode"
              ref={this.txtBarcode}
              onChange={this.handleBarcodeChange}
            />
          </div>
<div className="col-6">
    <input
              id="productName"
              onChange={this.handleNameChange}
            />
          </div>
</div>
);
  }
}
```

In Invoice component :

```
productModal = () => {
if (this.state.showProductModal) {
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <MDBModal
            isOpen={this.state.showProductModal}
            toggle={() => {
              this.setState({
                showProductModal: !this.state.showProductModal
              });
            }}
          >
            <MDBModalBody>
              <SearchProduct
                getProductData={this.getProductData}
                onCancel={() => this.setState({ showProductModal: false })}
              />
            </MDBModalBody>
          </MDBModal>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    }
}

render() {
return (
{this.productModal()}
<UnderInvoiceButtons
                productButtonClick={() =>
                  this.setState({ showProductModal: true })
                }
                customerSelected={(e) => this.handleCustomerInvoice(e)}
              />
  );
    }
```

Comment: You could just use the `autoFocus` attribute on the input...

Comment: @Lennholm I have tried it before, it does not work for me.

Comment: You're right, the error message would be different if the problem were what I mentioned in my (now deleted) answer, not the error you quoted. Sorry about that. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). I can't see any reason `focus` wouldn't be a function if `this.txtBarcode.current` is the `input` element.